# Why doesn't JSON have associative arrays?

Tags: arrays, json, yaml, associative-array

Why doesn't JSON have associative arrays? YAML does.

You can't do this in JSON:

```
{
    productsBySku: [
        12J432: {
            price: 49.99,
            qty_in_stock: 4
        },
        5X4352: {
            price: 29.99,
            qty_in_stock: 5
        }
    ]
}
```

But in YAML you can do:

```
productsBySku:
  - 12J432: 
        price: 49.99,
        qty_in_stock: 4
  - 5X4352:
        price: 29.99,
        qty_in_stock: 5
```

I'm wondering on a technical level why this decision might have been made for JSON.

Comment: JSON has ‘associative arrays’, they're called ‘objects’. Your YAML example is in fact an array containing two objects, so in JSON it would be: `"productsBySku": [ { "12J432": { ... } }, { "5X4352": { ... } } ]`

Comment: Why not? Because JSON is, by design, a subset of JavaScript. And JavaScript does not have associative arrays, no matter what others claim (object properties are not sorted).

Comment: Thank you. I am sorry if the question was inappropriate for SO. I just honestly like to understand reasons behind things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why doesn't JSON have associative arrays?

JSON doesn't have associative arrays in the PHP sense (e.g., *ordered* maps), but it certainly has key/value maps. They're called "objects."

> I'm wondering on a technical level why this decision might have been made for JSON.

Crockford designed JSON to be a subset of JavaScript's object initialiser syntax. JavaScript didn't have associative arrays (in the ordered map sense) at the time, and so JSON doesn't. *(Years afterward, JavaScript's standard library gained a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object which is **somewhat** like an associative array in that its entries are iterated in insertion order, but they don't have a literal form.)*

> YAML does

Does it? [I'm not seeing them](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963), and Biffen [seems to suggest otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26969120/why-doesnt-json-have-associative-arrays#comment42474577_26969120).

Reading the YAML spec, your YAML is exactly equivalent to this JSON (an array of objects, each with a single key referring to a subordinate object):

```
{
    "productsBySku": [
        {
            "12J432": {
                "price": 49.99,
                "qty_in_stock": 4
            }
        },
        {
            "5X4352": {
                "price": 29.99,
                "qty_in_stock": 5
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Even if YAML did have them, YAML ain't JSON<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)</sup>. ;-) They're different data notations, with different design goals. XML has namespaces, which JSON also doesn't have. YAML supports reusing nodes by reference, which allows for cyclical structures, which JSON doesn't.

> You can't do this in JSON

It depends on what you're trying to do. Again, as far as I can tell, your YAML is exactly the same as the JSON above.

If your goal is to have that list of products by SKU, you can:

```
{
    "productsBySku": {
        "12J432": {
            "price": 49.99,
            "qty_in_stock": 4
        },
        "5X4352": {
            "price": 29.99,
            "qty_in_stock": 5
        }
    }
}
```

The `productsBySku` property is an object. Its properties are not *ordered*, so it's not an ordered map, but it is a map. If you needed the properties within it to have order, you'd have to add a property to them indicating what the order was, and then apply that order after deserializing.

Alternately, you can use an array and then build your map after deserializing:

```
{
    "productsBySku": [
        {
            "sku": "12J432",
            "price": 49.99,
            "qty_in_stock": 4
        },
        {
            "sku": "5X4352",
            "price": 29.99,
            "qty_in_stock": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

---

<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)</sup> For those who don't know, YAML stands for "YAML Ain't Markup Language."

Answer (score 1):

JSON stand for JavaScript Object Notation. As it says, it's a javascript object like structure.
In JavaScript you don't have `associative arrays`. But you have `object` that have a similar structure.

So similar to your example you can have :

```
{
"productsBySku": {
    "12J432": {
        "price": 49.99,
        "qty_in_stock": 4
    },
    "5X4352": {
        "price": 29.99,
        "qty_in_stock": 5
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Because as JSON stands for *JavaScript Object Notation* and JavaScript itself *has objects* which can work **like** associative arrays, you would do this (note I had to fix the lack of quots in property names to produce a valid JSON sample):

```
{
    "productsBySku": {
        "12J432": {
            "price": 49.99,
            "qty_in_stock": 4
        },
        "5X4352": {
            "price": 29.99,
            "qty_in_stock": 5
        }
    }
}
```

...and you can iterate object properties using `for..in`:

```
for(var property in obj.propductsBySku) {
    // You don't want properties from the prototype
    if(obj.productsBySku.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
       var propertyValue = obj.productsBySku[property];
    }
}
```

You can also get all keys using `Object.keys(obj.productsBySku)`.

### OP said...

> But JSON objects can't be used like associative arrays, since they're
>   not ordered, right? I mean you can't do a forEach through an object's
>   properties in JavaScript, which if it were treated like an associative
>   array, you could. Am I wrong?

You're right about ordering, but object properties can be still iterated using `forEach`:

```
// Object.keys will return an array of own object property names
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(propertyName) {
   var propertyValue = obj[propertyName];
});
```

Objects can be used like hashes or associative arrays too, but you can't rely on order.

Comment: But JSON objects can't be used like associative arrays, since they're not ordered, right? I mean you can't do a forEach through an object's properties in JavaScript, which if it were treated like an associative array, you could. Am I wrong?

Comment: @CommaToast I've updated my answer to show you how you would use `forEach`.

Comment: OK, I accept that forEach can be used that way. I'm still at a loss as to why you can't have an ordered map, since I want to be able to have one where I can use dot-syntax on the map keys, or on the order. Guess you can't have it all.